# Do I need a degree in IT to apply for an EU Blue Card as a software engineer or is any degree enough?

Tags: working-visas, germany, immigration, eu, education

I am software engineer with 5 years of experience in Russia, have a Degree in Civil Engineering and want try to apply to the Blue Card program (country I am most interested is Germany).

I have read http://apply.eu/BlueCard/Germany/ and did not found any info that I need Degree in the field that I will work on.
http://www.make-it-in-germany.com/en/for-qualified-professionals/working/demanded-professions/scientists-and-it-specialists here at the bottom 'Foreign degrees' - it look like I will need to have appropriate degree future work field.

**so question: is it enough to have Degree in other field to apply to Blue Card?**
*In my case: I work in IT and and studied Civil construction.*

***Subquestion is*** - if I will have Master's in IT in an addition to my Civil Engineering study will it increase my chances to receive Blue Card? or important thing is only to have any university degree?

P.S. I understand that I will need to have good language knowledge, and be very proficient in my area to get job offer first.

Comment: The question is at the same time broad (covering multiple countries) and too specific (asking about your chances, which depend on a lot of personal factors). Maybe you could ask separate questions about the bachelor thing in Australia, Canada or the EU blue card separately. Note that the EU Blue Card did not replace the earlier schemes that exist all over Europe (e.g. *kennismigrant* in the Netherlands, *carte de séjour compétence et talent* in France) and the some countries like the UK do not even participate in it (the UK has a point-based system).

Comment: ok, thank you for you comment! I will split question

Comment: You do not need to learn German first to get a job offer in Germany, and it is not required for getting the "Blaue Karte EU". You just need a concrete job offer. Many companies offer relocation, and will often help with the blue card also. Berlin, Frankfurt or Munich (and maybe Hamburg) are the best shots for companies that do that as there are the most IT companies and expats are common. In fact, many Berlin startups hardly have Germans working there and everyone just speaks English. I have friends that have trouble learning German because of this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The EU directive is somewhat vague about that and the details are left to each individual participating state. In Germany, the relevant statute is the *Aufenthaltsgesetz* (“Residence act”). My reading of [article 19](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthg_2004/__19a.html) is that you do *not* need a degree in the exact same field (outside of regulated professions of course).

But you do need some recognised higher education (see [EU Blue Card FAQs](http://www.bamf.de/EN/Infothek/FragenAntworten/BlaueKarteEU/blaue-karte-eu-node.html)). You will also need to have it evaluated by the *Zentralstelle für ausländisches Bildungswesen*. Incidentally, I don't really know but I would guess that Civil Engineering counts as STEM.

In practice, you must fulfil two rather stringent requirements: You need a concrete job offer with a yearly salary over some threshold (depends on the occupation). To the extent it helps you find a job meeting the conditions, a master's degree in computer science could definitely be useful but if you manage to find a job in IT without one, you could still get a blue card (provided you have some other recognised university education of course).

I don't think the info you found on make-it-in-germany.com really contradicts all this. Clearly, language like “you *may* apply to have your degree verified” and “show [the equivalent German qualification] on your job applications” does not refer to a legal requirement. It's mostly about what you need to get a job. German employers are especially diploma and certification-oriented, it's customary to submit a whole bunch of certificates with each and every application so a clear equivalence with a German diploma would certainly help.

Note that unlike some other highly skilled migrant schemes, the EU Blue Card is not a point-based system, you either qualify or you do not. So you can't really increase or decrease your chances or compensate weaknesses in one area with other characteristics, you simply have to fulfil all the relevant requirements.

Comment: If the university the applicant attended is not in the database of accepted universities, it is neccecary to get the verification yourself, unless the embassy doesn't care, which can happen. It can also happen that they take it too literal and reject/ask for verification if the university is listed and the degree is listed, but not both together.

Comment: However, the document here https://www.daad.de/medien/deutschland/stipendien/formulare/sp-infoblatt_employment_2012_endfassung.pdf, page 5 states that for "IT specialists" and "language teachers", there's no need for any degree at all: `For jobs requiring qualified professional training, approval may be
issued for qualified workers with a recognised degree or a foreign university degree equivalent to a German university degree (Section 27 No. 1 Employment Regulation), to IT specialists (Section 27 No. 2 Employment Regulation) or language teachers (Section 26 Employment Regulation).`

Comment: Also this guy here says he doesn't have a degree even though he works as an "IT specialist" in Germany currently: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7074/blue-card-vs-regular-work-permit-for-it-specialists So it seems a bit confusing to me.

Comment: @XiangJi I am not sure what this is about, would you know the German name of this “Employment regulation”? In any case, that's completely unrelated to the Blue Card requirements.

Comment: @Gala Me neither. I tried to Google for it but found no answer. Maybe it would also be appropriate to send an email directly to DAAD to ask for clarification then. So in any case, to apply for a blue card, an adequate degree is a must then. I guess an A3 equivalent degree in computer science already suffices and I do not need to get a master's degree in that field, right?

Comment: @XiangJi It could be the https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beschäftigungsverordnung, which does include rules regarding language teachers but not “IT-Spezialisten”. I will keep looking.

Comment: The rules for the EU Blue Card are mostly separate and a degree is indeed necessary. You can find more info on equivalence between foreign and German diplomas in http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6568/diploma-for-blue-card-in-germany

Comment: @Gala Thank you. Could you help pointing out in the case of the question https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6568/diploma-for-blue-card-in-germany, where on the website is `Bedingt vergleichbar: Bakkalaureus/Bachelor 3j` listed on the Anabin database? I only saw Klasse: A3 listed in the form on the right hand side, without further details. Or is it `A3` is just equivalent to `Bedingt vergleichbar: Bakkalaureus/Bachelor 3j`?

Comment: Hi @JIXiang - what visa did you get? ? :)

Comment: @HelloWorldGuy I'm currently in Germany as a student so I didn't go through the route of applying for a job directly. Sorry I am unable to answer your question here.

Answer (score 2):

In germany, computer science degree is required for a developer's blue card, however, it is not required for national visa (any recognized degree will work).

Comment: actually it is not true, any "technical" degree is okay for blue card

Comment: A degree in business and accounting with 10 years experience will work?

Comment: @Enthusiast for a blue card I think not, but for a national visa I think yes