# Am I eligible for an EU Blue Card as a Network Engineer?

Tags: germany, blue-card

Please I Have an offer with an annual salary of 50.000 Euro in IT field ( as Network Engineer ) with more than 3 years of experience also I have the  approval from the the Federal Employment Agency  , my question is Am I eligible for the blue card ?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Hello @Andry Thank you for you response  my question is do I need to recognition ?  as I have my degree as BS degree and my university is H+ and for my diploma i find it as "Postgraduale Studienangebote" some people told me that for the shortage occupation 3 years of experience is enough . and I want to confirm if I can apply for the blue card without my degree just salary and experience ?

Comment: Hello @Samid, all of these questions were already answered, please see https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/7079/13223, https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/11288/eligible-for-germany-bluecard-with-a-non-anabin-listed-degree-and-a-h-univers, https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/6302/13223

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Network engineers can get a blue card. As long as you have a university degree, job and fulfil the minimum salary requirement, you can apply for the blue card.

Here is an excerpt from the [official website of Berlin](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/324659/en/).

**Minimum salary**
The amount you need to earn depends on your job.
If you work in a shortage occupation, you need to earn EUR 3,588 gross per month or more. (This equates to EUR 43,056 per year.) Shortage occupations are specific occupations for which there are not enough workers in Germany. These professions at present are: Scientists in natural science disciplines, mathematicians, architects, interior, urban and traffic planners, designers, engineers, scientific engineers, physicians (except dentists), and those with academic qualifications in information and communications technology.

If you are working in another profession, you will need to earn EUR 4,600 gross per month or more. (This equates to 55.200 Euro per year.)

Comment: Hi @thetravelgirl , Thank you for response  I do have my degree as BS degree and my university is H+  and for my diploma i find it as "Postgraduale Studienangebote"  some people told me that for the shortage occupation 3 years of experience is enough

Comment: here is the link on blue card  web site https://www.apply.eu/BlueCard/Germany/Germany.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I saw you ask this question under [my question](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7079/is-it-true-that-you-dont-need-a-degree-to-work-as-an-it-specialist-in-germany/20759) about working as an "IT specialist". Please note that getting the permit to work as an IT specialist is different from getting a Blue Card. In fact, there were people (Americans actually) in my company in Berlin who are great programmers and have many years of experience, but didn't have the corresponding university degree, and thus were not eligible for the Blue Card. They could only get the normal work visa. This could still be fine, depending on what you need.

Comment: Hi @xji Thank you so much for response   I do have my degree as BS degree and my university is H+ and for my diploma i find it as "Postgraduale Studienangebote" some people told me that for the shortage occupation 3 years of experience is enough

Comment: https://www.apply.eu/BlueCard/Germany/Germany.pdf

Comment: @SamidLadir I'm not sure I understood what "H+" means. As mentioned in your link, you might need to have your diploma recognized by KMK by providing e.g. the whole syllabus of the degree. https://www.kmk.org/zab/central-office-for-foreign-education.html. Any relocation agency should know the details. Experience is enough for obtaining a work visa, but as clearly indicated in the PDF file you posted, a "recognized" degree is a must for the Blue Card, no matter how stupid this rule might be.